# Is there a native wordlist for windows OS?

Tags: linux, windows, dictionary, spell-checking, words

For linux, there is the "words" file that comes natively with the system. Is there a windows counterpart for such dictionary files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While some software might add one, there is no dictionary file included by default in Windows. You can use Google to find a variety of dictionary files online or copy the one from a Linux computer if you need one. You'll have to distribute it with your software if necessary.